# windows 8 - keeps disconnection samsung from computer

Tags: adb, windows, samsung-kies, usb-drivers

I recently upgraded from windows xp to windows 8 and I have a problem with the USB-connection. When I plug-in my samsung galaxy s3 to the computer - a symbol pops-up and the adb-client can comunnicate with the server on the device. No problem here. But very often - the connection between the OS and the device suddenly dissappears - as if I hade disconnected the device from the computer. I do not know what causes this but I have a strong feeling that there may be a bug in windows 8. Why then - I have tried the following:

- changed USB cable
- reinstalled all drivers, including KIES
- even tried with my other cellphone - samsung galaxy s4 - same same same!!!!
- NO problem whatsoever when developing on XP
- tried with every USB-port on the computer
- AND - its not the usb-ports since this does not occur with other devices such as usb-memories

It feels like something in the OS close the samsung-driver but I cannot understand why?

One more thing - I am not sure about this - but this problem seems to be more frequent when I develop apps in eclipse.

So my question? Does anyone recognize this issue? I have googled and can only find problem with the adb-driver. Not issues with connection-problems. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'll ask around. But to be honest when I (briefly) installed W8 my printer, my wireless keyboard, my gamepad, and my phone all stopped working so I got my money back. W8 is a travesty I wouldn't be surprised if it was to blame.

Comment: My first impulse would be to uninstall Kies. I haven't used the newer versions, but the older ones mess up the drivers and device detection constantly.

Comment: Windows 8 or 8.1? If you're using Win 8 upgrade to 8.1 and then try again. Win 8 is lot of crap. A free advice if you don't mind - Windows XP or Windows 7 are better OSes for developers than 8/8.1.

Comment: What Onix said, Kies needs ALL process terminated in order for it to not interfere with the USB drivers themselves. Get rid of that first!

Comment: I've tried to uninstall Kies but its the same as before. Just now I am considering which process or service in the OS that cause this disconnection? thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

May have been USB power management. This would have affected recently updated Windows 7 and Windows 8.x. This issue can come from both the Windows OS and the Android OS. For Windows, try https://superuser.com/q/749982/ For Android, try using the developer option "Stay awake", and turn off screen timeout. However, none of the options will keep USB powered up indefinitely - they still get disconnected, they just wait longer time.

To reconnect after being disconnected due to USB power management, go to Settings - Storage, and toggle between the MTP/PTP/None modes. A nudge should be enough to get ADB to reconnect. If it still doesn't reconnect, use `adb kill-server`, `adb devices`. The second command automatically issues `adb start-server` and wait until it's running, and then shows the status of connected devices. That way, you can quickly find out whether the USB connection has been restored.

Note that you may have to close and restart Eclipse.

If the advice doesn't work, I have a long list of troubleshooting guide that maybe I can share some time in the future, somewhere.